# flex/lex yacc/bison multithreaded environment

Tags: c, multithreading, parsing, yacc, lex

Can I use the code generated by flex/bison|lex/yacc in a **multithreaded** environment ? I'm afraid there are a lot of global variables. How can it be fixed ?

Comment: To you mean to parse various [unrelated] parts of some input over multiple threads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With flex you can use `%option reentrant` and with bison `%pure-parser` to generate re-entrant code that does not have global data. You may still need some sort of synchronization to prevent multiple threads using the same data blocks at the same time.